# file i/o not working

Tags: android, file-io

I am trying to test a simple file i/o program on android where i type in some text in 
EditText and when i click the Save Button, it writes the content in a file. and when i click the Load button it loads the content back into the EditText.

here is my code---

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

private EditText textBox;
private static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText1);

Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
Button loadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);

saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

String str = textBox.getText().toString();

try
{

PrintWriter PR=new PrintWriter(new File("text1.txt"));

PR.write(str);
PR.flush();
PR.close();

//textBox.setText("");
//---display file saved message---
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
"File saved successfully!",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//---clears the EditText---
textBox.setText("");
}

catch (IOException ioe)
{
 ioe.printStackTrace();
}

}

});


loadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

try
{
  File f=new File("text1.txt");

  BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

  String txt="";
      String str;    

  while((str=BR.readLine())!=null)
  {
      txt+=str;

  }

//---set the EditText to the text that has been
// read---
textBox.setText(txt);

BR.close();

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
"File loaded successfully!",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
catch (IOException ioe) {
ioe.printStackTrace();
}
}
});
}
}
```

`

why is it not working? Thanks in advance for any help. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have write permission in the manifest?

Comment: if @zapl's answer is great, why don't you just accept his answer :) That's would encourage people help you later .

Answer (score 5):

Using `new File("text1.txt")` as output does not work on Android. The current working directoy is always `/` which is not writable for your app. Use

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "text1.txt");
```

[getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) is the internal storage for newer phones.

Your app [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) has several paths that you can use if you want to store data in your app-private folder. Paths from `Environment` are in public places where you can simply read the data with a filemanager

And don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in case you want to write to those public paths