# Android need to save data from intent to file

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing a small app that's supposed to accept content from any other app and then save it to file and FTP it up to a server.

I've done everything, but I can't get this part to work:

```
    OutputStream f1 = new FileOutputStream("file2.txt");
    f1.write(intent.getExtras().get("data"));
    f1.flush();
    f1.close();
```

intent is what I get back from the send action and could be anything.

I'm getting a compiling error where f1.write is not compatible with the get result.

Help please!

Comment: what are you expecting from get("data") ?

Comment: First check whether here > intent.getExtras().get("data") > data comes or not ?

Comment: @njzk2 I'm expecting an office document, but am I wrong in saying I don't care, I just want to save it to file? Perhaps the correct question would then be, where do I get the local file name from, so I can FTP the original file?

Comment: @NiravRanpara If I send an Image, it works, using the many samples on stack overflow - but that casts the content to a Bitmap, I'm assuming I'm getting binary data - I just want to save the stream?

Comment: is it a byte[] ? (then why don't you just cast it ?)

Comment: I guess it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504904/file-i-o-not-working/13505045#13505045 - besides that `OutputStream` does not know how to write an `Object` you get from `get("data")`

Comment: is permission of <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ?

Comment: @zapl / Nirav Ranpara Access is not a problem, I have that permission.

Comment: PLEASE null check IF there is an extra with the intent AND if there is some object stored under the key that you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do there is

```
OutputStream f1 = new FileOutputStream("file2.txt");
Object data = intent.getExtras().get("data")
f1.write(data);
```

That does not work because `OutputStream` only knows how to write `byte` and `byte[]` data.

Things that you can do:

- put the data via `putByteArray(String key, byte[] value)` and retrieve it via `getByteArray (String key)`. That data can be written to a file. This option is only a good idea if the data is small. Transporting large files via an `Intent` does not work.
- use a `ContentProvider`/`ContentResolver` and use the [`openInputStream(Uri uri)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29) method for a `Uri` that you put into your `Intent`. That `Uri` should be in `intent.getData()`.
- put the path to the source file into the Intent, then open the file

Most data that you get from other apps should be an `Uri` already. So using

```
Uri data = intent.getData();
InputStream in = getContentResolver.getInputStream(data);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectoy(), "file2.txt"));
// copy in to out
```

is probably the best option.

Comment: Thanks, going to try it - wow I have a lot to understand still from Java's classes.

Comment: Can I ask for a sample on how to write the InputStream to the OutputStream ? out.write(in) does not work.

Comment: @HeinduPlessis for example by using http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-copy-one-stream-to-another-using-java - A buffersize of 8k (8 x 1024) is usually good

Answer (score 0):

Please Use below code to save data in file, it will solve your problem.

```
// For Create Files into Internal Memory of Application
public void mCreateAndSaveFile() {
    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("filename.txt");
        file.write(intent.getExtras().get("data"));
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
try {
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                    "filename", 0));
            out.write("create text file"); //intent.getExtras().get("data")
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Here is [Example](http://buildmobile.com/store-user-data-using-simple-text-files-and-apis-in-android/)

Comment: make sure <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />